# wxGLCanvas huge memory usage after resizing

Tags: c++, opengl, wxwidgets

I have created a simple wxGLCanvas for demonstrating OpenGl using wxWidgets. The demo is working fine except when resizing the window the memory usage increases from a few megabytes to almost 400 megabytes and it stays there and doesn't decrease, here are the code snippets.

```
// ctor
TriangleCanvas::TriangleCanvas(wxWindow* parent, wxGLAttributes& attribList)
    : wxGLCanvas(parent, attribList, wxID_ANY, { 0,0 }, wxDefaultSize),
    m_vbo(0), m_vao(0), ctx_attr(new wxGLContextAttrs)
{
    
    ctx_attr->CoreProfile().OGLVersion(4, 3).EndList();
    m_context = new wxGLContext(this, NULL, ctx_attr);
    Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &TriangleCanvas::OnPaint, this);
    Bind(wxEVT_SIZE, &TriangleCanvas::Resize, this);
}


// Paint method
void TriangleCanvas::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& event)
{
    wxPaintDC(this);
    SetCurrent(*m_context);
    shader->use();

    // set background to black
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // draw the graphics
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_ebo);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    
    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers();
}

void TriangleCanvas::Resize(wxSizeEvent& event) {
    event.Skip();
    glViewport(0, 0, event.GetSize().x, event.GetSize().y);

    if (!setup) {
        InitializeGLEW();
        SetupGraphics();
    }   
}
```

Comment: I hope that `setup` var is correctly initialized once you have a valid size, otherwise you are calling those Intial/Setup functions time and time and time.

Comment: the variable is correctly initialized, I changed it in SetupGrahics function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to use wxGLCanvas with an extension loader is to use a helper class and keep all OpenGL drawing in the cpp portion of that helper class.

For example, here is a small helper class for drawing a triangle:

glhelper.h

```cpp
#ifndef GLHELPER_H_INCLUDED
#define GLHELPER_H_INCLUDED

class GLHelper
{
public:
    bool InitGlew();
    void Render();
    void SetSize(int w, int h);

    bool InitData();
    void Cleanup();



private:
    unsigned int m_VBO, m_VAO, m_shaderProgram;
};


#endif // GLHELPER_H_INCLUDED
```

glhelper.cpp

```cpp
#include <GL/glew.h>

#ifdef __WXMSW__
    #include <GL/wglew.h>
#elif defined(__WXGTK__)
    #include <GL/glxew.h>
#endif // defined

#include "glhelper.h"

static const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}\0";
static const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n\0";

bool GLHelper::InitGlew()
{
    GLenum initStatus = glewInit();

    return initStatus == GLEW_OK;
}

bool GLHelper::InitData()
{
    unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    // check for shader compile errors
    int success;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // fragment shader
    unsigned int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    // check for shader compile errors
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // link shaders
    m_shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(m_shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(m_shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(m_shaderProgram);
    // check for linking errors
    glGetProgramiv(m_shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        return false;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // left
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // right
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f  // top
    };

    //unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_VBO);
    // bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s),
    // and then configure vertex attributes(s).
    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered
    //VBO as the vertex attribute's bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we
    //can safely unbind
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // You can unbind the VAO afterwards so other VAO calls won't accidentally
    //modify this VAO, but this rarely happens. Modifying other VAOs requires a
    //call to glBindVertexArray anyways so we generally don't unbind VAOs (nor
    // VBOs) when it's not directly necessary.
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    return true;
}

void GLHelper::Cleanup()
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &m_VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_VBO);
    glDeleteProgram(m_shaderProgram);
}

void GLHelper::Render()
{
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // draw our first triangle
    glUseProgram(m_shaderProgram);
    glBindVertexArray(m_VAO);
    // seeing as we only have a single VAO there's no need to bind it every
    //time, but we'll do so to keep things a bit more organized
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

void GLHelper::SetSize(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

And here is a short demo that uses this helper class to draw the trinagle.

demo.cpp

```
#include "wx/wx.h"

#include <wx/glcanvas.h>
#include "glhelper.h"

class wxGlewFrame: public wxFrame
{
    public:
        wxGlewFrame(wxWindow*);
        ~wxGlewFrame();
    private:
        void OnCanvasSize(wxSizeEvent&);
        void OnCanvasPaint(wxPaintEvent&);

        void InitGL();

        wxGLCanvas* m_canvas;
        wxGLContext* m_context;
        GLHelper m_helper;
};

wxGlewFrame::wxGlewFrame(wxWindow* parent)
    : wxFrame(parent,  wxID_ANY, wxString())
{
    // Create the canvas and context.
    #if wxCHECK_VERSION(3,1,0)
        // These settings should work with any GPU from the last 10 years.
        wxGLAttributes dispAttrs;
        dispAttrs.PlatformDefaults().RGBA().DoubleBuffer().EndList();

        wxGLContextAttrs cxtAttrs;
        cxtAttrs.PlatformDefaults().CoreProfile().OGLVersion(3, 3).EndList();

        m_canvas = new wxGLCanvas(this, dispAttrs);
        m_context = new wxGLContext(m_canvas, NULL, &cxtAttrs);

        if ( !m_context->IsOK() )
        {
            SetTitle("Failed to create context.");
            return;
        }
    #else
        int dispAttrs[] = { WX_GL_RGBA, WX_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, WX_GL_CORE_PROFILE,
                            WX_GL_MAJOR_VERSION ,3, WX_GL_MINOR_VERSION, 3, 0 };

        m_canvas = new wxGLCanvas(this, wxID_ANY, dispAttrs);
        m_context = new wxGLContext(m_canvas, NULL);

        // Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way to check if the
        // context is ok prior to wxWidgets 3.1.0.
    #endif // wxCHECK_VERSION

    // On Linux, we must delay delay initialization until the canvas has
    // been full created.  On windows, we can finish now.
    #ifdef __WXMSW__
        InitGL();
    #elif defined(__WXGTK__)
        m_canvas->Bind(wxEVT_CREATE, [this](wxWindowCreateEvent&){InitGL();});
    #endif // defined
}

wxGlewFrame::~wxGlewFrame()
{
    m_helper.Cleanup();
    delete m_context;
}

void wxGlewFrame::OnCanvasSize(wxSizeEvent& event)
{
    wxSize sz = event.GetSize();
    m_helper.SetSize(sz.GetWidth(), sz.GetHeight());
    event.Skip();
}

void wxGlewFrame::OnCanvasPaint(wxPaintEvent&)
{
    wxPaintDC dc(m_canvas);

    m_helper.Render();
    m_canvas->SwapBuffers();
}

void wxGlewFrame::InitGL()
{
    // First call SetCurrent or GL initialization will fail.
    m_context->SetCurrent(*m_canvas);

    // Initialize GLEW.
    bool glewInialized = m_helper.InitGlew();

    if ( !glewInialized )
    {
        SetTitle("Failed it initialize GLEW.");
        return;
    }

    SetTitle("Context and GLEW initialized.");

    // Initialize the triangle data.
    m_helper.InitData();

    // Bind event handlers for the canvas. Binding was delayed until OpenGL was
    // initialized because these handlers will need to call OpenGL functions.
    m_canvas->Bind(wxEVT_SIZE, &wxGlewFrame::OnCanvasSize, this);
    m_canvas->Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &wxGlewFrame::OnCanvasPaint, this);
}

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
    public:
        virtual bool OnInit()
        {
            wxGlewFrame* frame = new wxGlewFrame(NULL);
            frame->Show();
            return true;
        }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

(This is basically the [Hello Triangle](https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL/blob/master/src/1.getting_started/2.1.hello_triangle/hello_triangle.cpp) sample from [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle) except rewritten to use wxGLCanvas and GLEW instead of GLFW and GLAD.

This takes up about 19MB of memory on my system and only increases up to about 24 or 25MB when resizing.  That might sound like a lot for such a simple program, but the running the official "Hello Triangle" sample uses 26MB.  So I think the memory usage is about what should be expected.

Comment: Any source/citation for that "delayed init on Linux" stuff?

Comment: No.  I just know it doesn't work for me if I don't wait for the creation event.  Actually in a [discussion of the wxWidgets' forum](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?p=208748&sid=fcb0be342e49c9d36e9b43232e4b85e7#p208748) a contributor who has done a lot of work on wxGLCanvas says you should wait even longer: until the canvas has a positive size and `IsShownOnScreen()` is true.  OpenGL can be so picky and driver dependent, it might be best to follow that advice.